# hdmi_cvt ignored on my boot/config.txt

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, config.txt, lcd, hat

I am testing a LCD HAT ( ST7735S ) that I bought and it is working great with fbcp, but I can´t get raspberry pi os to run at native screen resolution ( 128x128 ). I´ve been reading all documentation on bood/config.txt but nothing seems to work, even on cli mode, this is what I have so far in the config:

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_force_mode=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_cvt=128 128 60 4 0 0 0
enable_uart=1
start_x=0
```

any help is appreciated